# ReactJS key prop not working in CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, reactjs

I have a simple object with some details in which are looped and outputted using JS map() function.

See the Codepen here: http://codepen.io/matt5409/pen/YpeBWd?editors=0111

The bit to note is:

```
return(
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="example"
      transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
      transitionEnter={false} transitionLeave={false}>

    <li key={person.toString()}>{person.name}, {person.age}</li>

    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
)
```

The console is logging an error about key props, which, according to the official documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) I am implementing correctly.

Interestingly, if I remove the ReactCSSTransitionGroup component only the first item in the list appears. And if I remove the key={}, all three appear (complete with the console error).

What is going on here?

The goal is to have the function loop through each item in the list, and animate it on as defined by the ReactCSSTransitionGroup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the key props to the ReactCSSTransitionGroup component not the child li tag. Also using an index parameter in your map function to populate the key.

Something like this will work

```
peopleList.map(function(person, index){
    return(
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          key={index}
          transitionName="example"
          transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
          transitionEnter={true}
          transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
          transitionLeave={true}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}
         >

        <li key={index}>{person.name}, {person.age}</li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Khang - I actually already tried applying the key to the ReactCSSTransitionGroup but it didn't work. I have updated the Codepen to reflect the change, please feel free to fork it.

Comment: I can see it's working in your updated Codepen link. The three li fade in slowly. Isn't that what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need a different approach if you want it to fade in one by one. CSS alone won't cut it as there's no way to inform if the transition of the previous one did finish.

Comment: Yea. I'm looking at React Motion (https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) now. How very disappointing that I can't achieve this with transition group. Thanks.

Comment: You can try giving each component state, and use setTimeout for each of them (in componentWillMount) based on the index number.

Comment: set timeout had crossed my mind but it feels a bit scrappy.